# Detect and/or fail fast when attempting to load a docx package with EPPlus

Tags: epplus

I'm using EPPlus v6.1 and am adding in some detection of failure scenarios such as non-Excel files, which is working fine for non office files but is not working as expected for non-Excel files packed in the OfficeXml format such as Word docs. I would have expected it to fail in the `new ExcelPackage(file)` constructor or that the loaded package would expose a property that clearly determines that the file is a Word doc (or at least not an Excel doc).

There is no way that I can see to gracefully fail in this scenario. Some of the exposed properties will throw an exception, but the only non-exception flow that seems reasonable is checking that the Workbook.WorkSheets count is zero, although that seems to be a valid Excel scenario however unlikely or of little use it might be.

Is there a way to check for non-Excel files that doesn't rely on Exceptions, file extensions, testing against potentially valid Excel scenarios, or cracking open the raw XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the xml-based office files are just zip archives and only xlsx files have a folder named "xl" on the top level, this should work:

```
using FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\tmp\excel.xlsx", FileMode.Open);
using System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive za = new System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive(fs, ZipArchiveMode.Read);
if (!za.Entries.Any(e => e.FullName.StartsWith("xl/")))
{
 // not an excel file          
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm hoping there's a way to do this without cracking open the archive and relying on an implementation detail, ideally something EPPlus specific to avoid opening the file twice at all. I'll come back to this answer if something more targeted to the scenario does't come up.